# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database

Tags: php, oop

i have fetal error message say :

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Database in C:\wamp\www\pets_new\lib\database.php on line 3

```
require_once("lib/message.php");
require_once("lib/user.php");
```

and all connect to database class

Class message

```
<?php

require('database.php');

class Message{
```

Class user :

```
<?php

require('database.php');

class User{
```

Comment: Your 2-line snippet is not `database.php`, is it?

Comment: evry class of them contain this line
require_once("lib/database.php") ;

Comment: Check inside your user.php or message.php file. You have already include a database.php file where class Database is already declared.

Answer (score 9):

You include 2 files in a single "run". Think of it like this: All the included files are put together by PHP to create one big script. Every `include` or `require` fetches a file, and pastes its content in that one big script.

The two files you are including, both *require* the same file, which declares the `Database` class. This means that the big script that PHP generates looks like this:

```
class Message
{}
class Database
{}//required by message.php
class User
{}
class Database
{}//required by user.php
```

As you can see class `Database` is declared twice, hence the error.
For now, a quick fix can be replacing the `require('database.php');` statements with:

```
require_once 'database.php';
```

Which checks if that particular file hasn't been included/required before. If it has been included/required before, PHP won't require it again.
A more definitive and, IMHO, better solution would be to register an autoloader function/class method, and let that code take care of business.

More on how to register an autoloader [can be found in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). If you go down this route, you'd probably want to take a look at the coding standards concerning class names and namespaces [here](http://www.php-fig.org). If you conform to those standards, you don't have to write your own autoloader, and can simply use the universal class loader from Symfony2, or any other framework that subscribes to the PHP-FIG standards (like CodeIgnitor, Zend, Cake... you name it)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this , while declaring class

```
if(  !class_exists('database') ) {
    require('database.php');
}
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Seems sometimes you need. I've just encountered such a case, so this helped me (and no, no mix of `require()` and `require_once()` in my case. I think here it was caused by symlinks).

Comment: If you need the `class_exists`, you probably could do with a better autoloader. `class_exists`, unless specified otherwise, invokes the autoloader which looks for files throughout the include path. If those can't be found, `class_exists` returns false. If you need to manually include/require files, chances are you're doing something wrong. I work on big projects (often north of 1 million LoC), and I never use `require` or `require_once` outside of tests...

Answer (score 0):

This means that you've already declared the class Database, the second time it's loaded (where ever the copy is), it's causing the error. We cannot see your content of the two files you've quoted. However, I'm sure if you look in both of them you'll find at least two creations of the class Database. One needs to be removed.

Comment: all clases need the main clas databse.php

Comment: Yes, but if you're including database.php in the main file. But also including in every other file that you're including in the main file. You'll have the error that way.

Comment: @AD7six: And that's why we use autoloaders ;-P